Invariance of the resultant under change of polynomials
Wikipedia states that the resultant of two monic polynomials $a,b\in K[x]$ remains the same, if one replaces $b$ with $(b-qa)$, where $q\in K[x]$ is another polynomial:
$$\mathrm{res}(a,b) = \mathrm{res}(a,b-qa).$$
Is this really acurate?

Whats about this counterexample: $a = (x-2), b = (x-3)(x+3), q = (x-3)$.
Then $b-qa = (2+3)x - 2 \cdot 3 - 3^2 = 5x -15 = 5(x-3)$
Therefore
$$\mathrm{res}(a,b) = (2+3)(2-3) = -5 \neq -1 = (2-3) = \mathrm{res}(a,b-qa).$$

I can see however, that
$$\mathrm{res}(a,b) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{res}(a,b-qa) = 0,$$
since
$$(x-x_0) \mid a \Rightarrow \big(\; (x-x_0) \mid b \;\Leftrightarrow\; (x-x_0) \mid b-qa \;\big)$$
holds.
But this is not the statement made in wikipedia and this alone would not allow the calculation of the resultant using the euclidian algorithm.

Have a look here.

Could you elaborate further, how this helps?

I don't see how your counterexample holds --- $\mathrm{res}(a,b) = \mathrm{res}(x-2, x^2-9) = -5$ is true, but $\mathrm{res}(a, b-qa) = \mathrm{res}(x-2,(x^2-9)-(x+1)(x-2)) = \mathrm{res}(x-2, x-7) = -5$, which is what Wikipedia says we'd get.  Where are you getting $9$?

@apnorton you are right. I had an error in the counterexample. However, with different numbers the counterexample still works. I edited the counterexample.

I found a proof for $\mathrm{res}(a,b) = \mathrm{res}(a,b-qa)$ (see below).
Using the proof I now see the error in my "counterexample" (even after my first revision of the counterexample):
$b-qa$ is not monic.
The formula for the resolvent is not
$$\mathrm{res}(a,b) = \prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^m (\beta_j-\alpha_i)$$
but
$$\mathrm{res}(a,b) = \mathrm{lc}(a)^m \mathrm{lc}(b)^n \prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^m (\beta_j-\alpha_i),$$
where $n = \deg(a)$ and $m = \deg(b)$.
Therefore in my counterexample $\mathrm{res}(a,b-qa)$ is not $(2-3)$, but $5(2-3) = -5$ which is indeed the same as $\mathrm{res}(a,b)$.

I will now present the proof:
Theorem Let $q\in K[x]$ and $\deg(b-qa) \lt \deg(b)$. Then the following holds:
$$\mathrm{res}(a,b) = \mathrm{lc}(a)^{m-m'} \mathrm{res}(a,b-qa),$$
with $m' := \deg(b-qa)$ and $m := \deg(b)$.
In particular, if $a$ is monic then
$$\mathrm{res}(a,b) = \mathrm{res}(a,b-qa).$$

Proof Let $a = \mathrm{lc}(a) \prod_{i=1}^n (x-\alpha_i)$ and $b = \mathrm{lc}(b) \prod_{j=1}^m (x-\beta_j)$.
Then
$$\begin{alignat}{3}
\mathrm{res}(a,b) &\;=\; \mathrm{lc}(a)^m \mathrm{lc}(b)^n \prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^m (\beta_j-\alpha_i) & \\
&\;=\; \mathrm{lc}(a)^m \prod_{i=1}^n \mathrm{lc}(b) (-1)^{m} \prod_{j=1}^m (\alpha_i - \beta_j) \;\;&=\; (-1)^{m \cdot n} \mathrm{lc}(a)^m \prod_{i=1}^n b(\alpha_i). \\
\end{alignat}$$
Let furthermore $b = qa + r$ for $q,r\in K[x]$ and $\deg(r) \lt \deg(b)$.
Then
$$\begin{alignat}{3}
\mathrm{res}(a,b) &\;=\; (-1)^{m \cdot n} \mathrm{lc}(a)^m \prod_{i=1}^n b(\alpha_i) & \\
&\;=\; (-1)^{m \cdot n} \mathrm{lc}(a)^m \prod_{i=1}^n (qa+r)(\alpha_i) & \\
&\;=\; (-1)^{m \cdot n} \mathrm{lc}(a)^m \prod_{i=1}^n r(\alpha_i) & \\
&\;=\; \mathrm{lc}(a)^{m-m'}  (-1)^{m \cdot n} \mathrm{lc}(a)^{m'} \prod_{i=1}^n r(\alpha_i) & \\
&\;=\; \mathrm{lc}(a)^{m-m'} \mathrm{res}(a,r) \;&\;=\; \mathrm{lc}(a)^{m-m'} \mathrm{res}(a,b-qa). \\
\end{alignat}$$
$\square$
Source: Zassenhaus, H. (1989), Algorithmic Algebraic Number Theory, Cambridge University Press, pp. 56–58, doi:10.1017/CBO9780511661952, ISBN 9780511661952

This answer contains different formulas, in particular
$$\mathrm{Res}(f-\alpha g , f-\beta g) = (\alpha - \beta)^d \cdot \mathrm{Res}(f , g)$$
(where $\alpha, \beta$ are scalars) showing that your formula
$$\mathrm{Res}(a,b) = \mathrm{Res}(a,b-qa)$$
doesn't hold even in the case where $q$ is a scalar.

I don't see why the formula shows this. You imply that $f=b$ and $g=a$. Then $a=b-\alpha a \Leftrightarrow \alpha = \frac{b-a}{a}$ is not a scalar...
